# margin stops working when float is not used

Tags: css

why does margin stops working when I take out float property? Is there a relation that I don't know?

```
.header-image {
   float: left;
   width: 33%;
   margin-top: 1em;
   padding-right: 3em;
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Probably margin collapse.

Comment: Could you pls offer a reproducible example ?

Comment: No context, Abstract answer: Floats create a [**`Block formatting contexts`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and a `block formatting context` does stuff to margins

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of your context, but @Alohci might be correct.

> Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

For more information of [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

I try to reproduce your issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4dn1h7p/1/)

```html
<div class="container" >
  
  <div class="block1">block1</div>
  <div class="block2">block2</div>

</div>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  /* display: inline-block; margin works again with inline-block */ 
  /* border: 1px black solid; add border could help also the margin collapse */
}
.block1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.block2 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px
}
.block1 {
   width: 33%;
   margin-top: 1em;
   padding-right: 3em;
   text-align: right;
}
```